# Specifying the Code Analysis output file for multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am trying to build a solution using MSBuild and I would like to fire off code analysis for each project and have all of the output placed into a certain directory. The command I am running is:

```
msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=True;CodeAnalysisLogFile=c:\BuildOutput\code-analysis.xml
```

The problem I am having is that the code analysis overwrites the xml file for each project in the solution, so I only get the output for the last project that is built.  Is there a way I can tell MSBuild to append the output for code analysis or to generate a unique file for each output?

Note:  I would prefer not having to update each CSProj files with the CodeAnalysisLogFile xml tag, but if there is no other way, then that is what I will do.

Comment: I cannot even get a log file to be produced at all, not even one that is overwritten for each project.  :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a or use an existing common "Imports.Props" file imported , and in it include a definition for CodeAnalysisLog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisLogFile>$(OutputPath)\CodeAnalysis\$(AssemblyName).$(Platform).$(Configuration).xml</CodeAnalysisLogFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then in your project files import this common props file:

```
<Import Project="$(PropertyOfSourceFolder)\CodeAnalysis.props" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `CodeAnalysisLogFile` argument to a relative path like this:

`CodeAnalysisLogFile=code-analysis.xml`

This will create separate log files for the code analysis done on each project. The file will appear separately within each project directory.

I cannot seem to figure out a way for them to all be in one log file though...seems like something that should be supported, just all errors for a single solution in one log file.

Comment: While this doesn't seem to work for this particular question, This is what I was looking for. Thank You